# Does bootstrap provide content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousellite

I am trying to achieve a responsive web-page using bootstrap and used a jcarousellite j-query plugin for content sliding with images..

now the vertical slider works fine but i am unable to achieve the bootstrap responsiveness when i resize my browser.when the browser is resized the image appears but no text appears..

is there any alternative...

this is the code below

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="bootstrap  /css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-custom.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/components.css"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="css/superslide.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/img.css">


<body>
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-5">


<div class="row">

<div class = "col-xs-8 col-md-8 news">
<div class = "p1">NEWS</div>
</div>

<div class = "col-xs-4 col-md-4 news">
<a><button class="icon-up"></button></a>
<a><button class="icon-down"></button></a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="newsticker-demo" class = "newsticker-jcarousellite">
<ul>
<li class = "row">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">

<img id = "myImage" src="asset/1.png">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9"> 


<p>sdsds</p>
<p><a href="#">blah</a></p>

<p>blah</p>
</div>

</li>           

<li class = "row">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">


<p>sds</p>
<p><a href="#">blah</a></p>

<p>blah</p>
</div>

</li>

<li class = "row">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">

<img src="asset/3.png">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">


<p>sds</p>
<p><a href="#">blah</a></p>

<p>blasdsdsdssdsdsdsdsdsdddddddddddddddddd</p>
</div>


</li>       
</ul>



</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jcarousellite_1.0.1c4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>

</html>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can call the "Carousel" a content slider so yes. Bootstrap provides one.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You need to include the `bootstrap.min.js` and `carousel.css`

https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: but for the vertical slider i am using jcarsousellite and within that i have added bootstrap classes..what is preventing from getting the responisveness?